# pandas to_datetime doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` whose entries are mostly `'yyyymmdd'` date strings but there are also some `'nan'` values. Note that here these `'nan'` are *strings* instead of the float nan. Now I want to convert all the date strings in the df to pandas datetime format, while converting the `nan` values to `NaN`, `NaT` etc, whatever can be detected by `pd.isnull`.

An immediate thought would be using the [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function with the `errors` argument. As said in the documentation,

> `errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}`, default `'raise'`
>   - If `'raise'`, then invalid parsing will raise an exception 
>   - If `'coerce'`, then invalid parsing will be set as `NaT` 
>   - If `'ignore'`, then invalid parsing will return the input

So, I tried with my example `df`

```
            001002.XY 600123.AB 123456.YZ 555555.GO
ipo_date     20100203  20150605       nan  20090501
delist_date       nan  20170801       nan       nan
```

where all values are `str` and even `nan` are actually `'nan'`. I then tried `pd.to_datetime(df, errors='coerce')`, which throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-27-43c41318d6ab>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(df, errors='coerce')
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 512, in to_datetime
    result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors=errors)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 591, in _assemble_from_unit_mappings
    "[{0}] is missing".format(','.join(req)))
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

However, if I tried with individual cells, it worked out fine:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0, 0])
Out[33]: 
Timestamp('2010-02-03 00:00:00')
pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[1, 0])
Out[34]: 
NaT
```

I can't figure out what happened. For what it's worth though, all columns have `object` as `dtype`:

```
df.dtypes
Out[35]: 
001002.XY    object
600123.AB    object
123456.YZ    object
555555.GO    object
dtype: object
```

But this doesn't seem to be the culprit: I tested with individual columns too, and they worked out fine:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0])
Out[36]: 
ipo_date      2010-02-03
delist_date          NaT
Name: 001002.XY, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Could someone help or explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be done slightly differently - applying `pd.to_datetime` to all columns:

```
In [6]: df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
Out[6]:
             001002.XY  600123.AB 123456.YZ  555555.GO
ipo_date    2010-02-03 2015-06-05       NaT 2009-05-01
delist_date        NaT 2017-08-01       NaT        NaT
```

If you pass a DataFrame to `pd.to_datetime()` - it expects columns like (year, month, day and optionally: hour, minute, second) in order to combine a datetime from separate columns.

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys
>   can be common abbreviations like [`year`, `month`, `day`, `minute`,
>   `second`, `ms`, `us`, `ns`]) or plurals of the same

Comment: Thanks! I really should have looked up the examples provided in the doc. It's just that since it works with `Series` I naturally expects it to work with `DataFrame`, similarly in a `applymap` fashion. But it doesn't.